# Showing information at the bottom of the last page in the report

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I would like to show long text ( several paragraphs) at the bottom of a report using SSRS 2008 R2.

I have been searching around but it seems that there aren't any available solutions. If I put the a text box in the footer and then reference to a hidden field in the report body, then on the intermediate pages, there would be a big plank gap in the footer, which apparently isn't what I want.

Could you guys provide me with some solution for that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The dedicated footer section is a *page* footer, not a *report* footer - it is intended to appear on *every* page.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the trick by adding footer in your report.

- Add a footer in the report
- Add one Text box in that footer with your description
- Remove footer border and Draw your own line above textbox(If you want to show footer separetly)
- Add following condition to the TextBox visibility expression

> =IIf(Globals!PageNumber = Globals!TotalPages, False, True)

Comment: I would suggest using a rectangle and suppressing the rectangle.  Also make sure that "Consume Containing Whitespace" is set to "True"

Answer (score -1):

Put the TextBox at the end of the report and not in the footer in the design view.

Then the Text box will appear in the end of the report.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry, could you pleas elaborate on this? How could I stick the text box to the end of the report?

Comment: Right Click on the report body -> Insert -> Page Footer this is the way you insert the page footer. Does your report contain the page footer?. If yes there will be section for the footer with the dotted lines in the bottom of the page. There If you had inserted the textbox will repeat for all the pages. If you want the textbox only in the end of the report put it above the dotted lines section.

Comment: I have tried your suggestions but it didn't work. If my content end at the middle of the page, then the content of the text box would be right after the content. Do I have to set any property on the text box?

Comment: Make sure the textbox is the last control in the content. If not then it will be occur in the middle. No Property needs to set.